# Details of generation programs supplied with nauty

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, nauty

The program `nauty` comes with `gtools` which contains, among others, several generation programs like geng, genbg, ... I was wondering whether there is some article or other source describing the details of the algorithm used. I assume that the technique described in 'Isomorph-free exhaustive generation' is used, but I was interested in knowing which construction operations are used for each class and which was the criterion to select the parent for a given graph.

The main reason I want to know this, is that I see that there is the possibility to write plugins for these generation programs, but I would like to know a bit more about the program details before I try to find efficient ways to bound the process to get to the specific structures I'm interested in.

Comment: Did you mean to ask this question on StackOverflow?

Comment: No, it's seems more suited for MathOverflow, since I'm mostly asking about the alghorithmic side of the program and not the actual implementation details. Of course the boundary between the two is thin.

Comment: [B. D. McKay, Isomorph-free exhaustive generation, J. Algorithms 26 (1998) 306-324](http://users.cecs.anu.edu.au/~bdm/papers/orderly.pdf)
according to the [mailing list](https://mailman.anu.edu.au/pipermail/nauty/2006-August/000367.html).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

MathOverflow is not a good place for questions like this. The best place for technical questions about *nauty* is the [mailing list](http://mailman.anu.edu.au/mailman/listinfo/nauty).

Anyway, the parent of a graph $G$ is a graph $G-v$ where $v$ is some vertex.  In *geng* you can assume $v$ has the maximum degree in $G$.  In *genbg* you can assume that $v$ is on the right side of $G$ and has the maximum degree there. In each case there is more to the story, but the details depend on the parameters and it doesn't strike me as a good idea to assume any more when writing plugins.

Comment: Thanks. The plugin was of course only one reason. Curiosity being the other. ;-) I will have a look at the mailing list.